# C# Throw Exceptions to top level functions and then log them

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following exception handling code:

```
private void foo (){
  try{ 
     foo1(); 
  }
  catch(Exception ex){ 
     if (ex is specificException){ //Catch only the exceptions that I can really handle
         // log the exception
         // Display a message to the user that something went wrong. 
         return;
     }
     throw; 
  }
}

private void foo1(){
  try{
       // code that could throw an exception
  }
  catch{
    throw;
  }
}
```

So the question is:

Should I keep using this approach to handle the exceptions or should I log all the exceptions in the low level functions and then throw them?

P.S 
I catch all the unhandled exceptions and then gracefully close the application.

Comment: This is quite an opinion based question. Some code styles prefer catching exceptions as close to their origin as possible, other prefer to propagate them.

Comment: Typically you get all the exception in the stacktrace. Very useful especially if you work a big project in a team

Comment: Just for note, you can have multiple catch clauses which eliminates the usage of `if (ex is specificException)`

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the point of catching an exception in `foo1` if it's going to be re-thrown and caught again at the calling statement. Seems hideous.

Comment: Go through this link, it discuss [best practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, you should avoid using try/catch unless you're looking to trap a specific kind of exception.

### Example of bad use for try/catch

```
try {
   //some work
}
catch(Exception e) {
   //this is bad, it traps everything!
}
```

### Good use good use for try/catch

```
try {
   //some work
}
catch(ArguementNullException e) {
   //good, we only trapped the one exception we were interested in, everything is is thrown
}
```

So how do we handle Exceptions then if we don't have try/catch all over the place?  The answer is using an automatic logging tool to do it for you.  [Elmah](https://www.nuget.org/packages/elmah/) is a great example, you install the Nuget package and wallah, all your exceptions are logged automatically and you can view them.

Comment: Except *ArgumentNullException* is an exception which should be not caught, but avoided.

Comment: true, that was just the first one that came to mind